# Close votes "invalidated"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I had voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73300661/283366) as *"not reproducible"* and provided a [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codemirror-example-codemirror-6-forked-zss0yw?file=/src/CodeMirrorTest.jsx) to prove it.

Today, I got pinged by a response from OP and noticed the vote was gone. I tried to vote again thinking I must have forgotten to do so and received this new message...

> You have already voted to close this question, but you may vote again on Sep 8 at 3:00

What is this all about? Looking in the timeline, I see [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73300661/timeline#review_32450544)

> Close votes
> invalidated

What does that even mean? Why was my quite legitimate close vote removed?

Comment: Basically, it means the [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/32450544) timed out due to not getting any votes.

Comment: @RyanM the timeline entry is hard to understand since it has two dates. What does that mean? Also, 4 days seems quite short for a timeout

Comment: The first date is when the task was enqueued; the second is when it timed out.  And yeah, it's potentially kind of short, but the usefulness of a question getting closed decreases as it gets older, and also the close vote review queue on Stack Overflow is notoriously overloaded.  It has to give up at some point, and that was the cutoff that was chosen at some point in the past.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. I had no idea that individual votes could time out and I've been here a long time (almost as long as you)

Comment: Technically, the close votes age away slower than the review.  For example, your close vote (cast Aug 10) aged away Aug 25 (which I can see as a moderator), while the review task aged away Aug 14.

Comment: From new comments: "It is resolved. Somehow other component was forcing it to behave like that. Removed that component and it worked fine.Thanks " This should *definitely* be closed as not reproducible now.

Comment: Close-votes, reopen-votes, and close-flags are aged away between 3.5 to 4.5 days after being cast if the question has > 100 views. That timeframe is 13.5 to 14.5 days if the question has <= 100 views. When the aging away happens within those ranges depends on when the vote was cast relative to when the job which performs the aging away task is run during the day. Both timeframes may be extended by an additional day or days, depending on if other people cast close-votes (or reopen votes) on the question and when they cast them. You can recast your vote 14 days after your last one aged away.

Comment: See the duplicates for a long-form version of Makyen's comment. And they say Meta is not a helpful place. :-)

Comment: Thanks again @Makyen . The missing term for me was _"aged"_. Perhaps the timeline should say that instead of _"invalidated"_ which has quite negative connotations

Comment: @Phil The Close votes *review task* was invalidated. Your close-vote aged away. The timeline does, actually, say that your close-vote "aged away", but the entries for the actual close-votes in timelines are only displayed to moderators. I *thought* the close-votes list in the user profile *used to* say that the vote aged away, but that information is not displayed at this point, so you have to *assume*. [I checked on one of my own aged-away close-votes from before I became a moderator, because moderators can't see other peoples' close-votes in their profiles, but can in question timelines.]